# Performance differences between list of objects vs consumers

Tags: java, list, lambda, iteration

I have this method where some point are generated and added to a new list. This has the disadvantage of generating too many objects everytime.

Now, i thought about returning a consumer of point consumer, something like:

```
PointConsumer { void apply(int x, int y); }
PointIterator { void apply(PointConsumer pc); }
```

Everytime i generate a point, i would concatenate a new lambda with the old one:

```
pointIterator = pc -> { pointIterator.apply(pc); pc.apply(x, y); }
```

Would this approach be slower or more memory consumer than the previous one? Leaving aside if the differences are bigger or smaller.

Comment: Did you mean for the method names to be `accept` or `apply`?

Comment: What happens to those objects afterwards? If you need to keep them in memory anyway, then it's easier to add them to the list directly rather than through a consumer.

Comment: good point Bret Okken. Yole, the "point" is, regardless of the convenience, which one would be more efficient. I can tell which one is prettier

Comment: And what is a lambda than an object? You are creating a fancy linked list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a JMH benchmark of what I understood from your quite general question to be your idea. I hope it helps you make some conclusions about the efficiency you have asked about.

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(Measure.SIZE)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 100, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 200, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Threads(1)
@Fork(1)
public class Measure
{
  public static final int SIZE = 1;
  private static final int LIMIT = 50;

  interface PointConsumer { void apply(int x, int y); }
  interface PointIterator { void apply(PointConsumer pc); }

  PointIterator pointIterator;
  List<Point> points;

  @Setup public void setup() {
    pointIterator = pc -> {};
    range(0,LIMIT).forEach(x -> range(0,LIMIT).forEach(y -> {
      final PointIterator pi = pointIterator;
      pointIterator = pc -> { pi.apply(pc); pc.apply(x, y); };
    }));
    points = range(0,LIMIT).mapToObj(i->i).flatMap(
        x -> range(0,LIMIT).mapToObj(y -> new Point(x,y)))
        .collect(toList());
  }

  @Benchmark public int pointIterator() {
    final int sum[] = {0};
    pointIterator.apply((x,y) -> sum[0] += x + y );
    return sum[0];
  }

  @Benchmark public int list() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Point p : points) sum += p.x + p.y;
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Results of measurement:

```
Benchmark                    Mode  Samples   Score   Error  Units
o.s.Measure.list             avgt        5   3,921 ± 0,408  us/op
o.s.Measure.pointIterator    avgt        5  17,970 ± 1,740  us/op
```

My conclusions:

1. obviously, it is way slower than the plain `ArrayList` approach;
2. the same number of objects are created (the lexical environment closed over by a lambda is held in an object);
3. your design results in recursive evaluation, blowing up the stack for even modest list sizes.

Comment: Nice, thanks for taking the time to make the testing.